# route problem when confirming two factor with laravel fortify and inertiajs

Tags: laravel, inertiajs, two-factor-authentication, laravel-fortify

I have a `TwoFactorConfirm` page, where an OTP code input is expected after the 2fa device is set, and a `POST` request is made to `route('two-factor.confirm')` provided by `Fortify` like this:

```
const { data, setData, post, processing, errors, reset } = useForm({
    code: '',
});

const submit = (e) => {
    router.visit(route('two-factor.confirm'), {
        method: 'post',
        data: data,
        onSuccess: (page) => {
            router.visit(route('somewhere'))
        }
    });
}
```

After the confirmation is done I want to redirect the user to another page, but here is a problem: the `router.visit(route('somewhere'))` never get to run, because after the request is processed (db changed so it's ok to this step), I got a `GET` request to `/thispage?code=xxxxxx` instead of `route('somewhere')`. This part I don't really understands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Inertia router follows the redirect returned from the route `two-factor.confirm`

You can modify these redirects, explained in the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/fortify#customizing-authentication-redirects

```php
$this->app->instance(TwoFactorConfirmedResponse::class, new class implements Responsable {
    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        return redirect('/somewhere');
    }
});
```